# Why does python return a 0.0 for a function with a value

Tags: python, function

```
def on_base_percentage(h, bb, hbp, ab, sf):
    return float((h + bb + hbp)/(ab + bb + hbp + sf))

print on_base_percentage(1,2,3,4,5)
```

Why does Python print `0.0` when there is in fact a value to the function?

Comment: Because... it returns `float(0)`.

Comment: How do you get it to return the actual value as a decimal like how to get it to print the value as the one i calculated 0.42857...

Comment: Modify like this. `return float(X)/float(Y)`.

Comment: how would i orient this to get a float as well float(total_bases/int5)

Comment: actually i figured it out thanks again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function is basically evaluating:

```
(1 + 2 + 3)/(4 + 2 + 3 + 5)
```

or

```
6 / 14
```

I'm assuming you're using python2.x which is going to do *integer* division here (truncating the result to end up with an integer.  In this case, the truncated result is `0`, which you then use to construct a float (`0.0`).  An easy solution here is to just call float on either the numerator or the denomonator to force true division:

```
float((h + bb + hbp))/(ab + bb + hbp + sf)
```

Alternative solutions are enabling true_division:

```
from __future__ import division  # Needs to be imported first thing!
```

In that case, dividing integers will use ["true division"](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0238/).  (neat).

Comment: the thing is i would set it up to have the input values as floats but Im actually suppose to use integers for the input and get a float as the result

Comment: Do note that enabling float division in Python 2 (via the import) will confuse the hell out of anyone else who reads your code, so really isn't recommended.

Comment: @Deka -- Ok?  that's fine -- I showed you how.  Just change the return value to the stuff that I showed (`float((h + bb + hbp))/(ab + bb + hbp + sf)` rather than `float((h + bb + hbp)/(ab + bb + hbp + sf))`) and you'll be fine.  (notice the difference in parenthesis placement)

Comment: @sapi -- I disagree.  If you want integer division, use the integer division operator (`//`).  Since python3.x does true division by default, you should _always_ check whether or not true division is enabled when it matters.

Comment: actually i just have one more question how would i round the output of this to 4 digits                                                     def on_base_plus_slugging(on_base_percentage, slugging_percentage):   float(on_base_percentage)+float(slugging_percentage)

Comment: @mgilson I disagree simply because the integer division operator *is* `/` in Python 2; code is entitled to rely on people not changing the meaning of operators out from under it

Comment: but this is where I disagree.  In python2, the integer division operator is `//` and has been since [python2.2 over 10 years ago](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0238/) which is also when the `__future__` statement was introduced.  The operators might be changing from underneath you, but it has happened *very* slowly with **lots** of warning.  Why not get ready for the future now?

Comment: @mgilson it's a shame that it took so long for `//` to be prominently advertised in documentation. I certainly don't recall being aware of it back when 2.3 was current.

Answer (score 4):

You must cast to a float **before** you do the division, not after.

The division is performed, yielding `0` since it's division between integers. You then make `0` a float, printing `0.0` as the result.

Try this way

```
def on_base_percentage(h, bb, hbp, ab, sf):
    return float(h + bb + hbp)/float(ab + bb + hbp + sf)

print on_base_percentage(1,2,3,4,5)
0.428571428571
```

Comment: the thing is i have to use integers as my input values but i have to have a float as the result so how would i be able to get a float this way